# Using the nightly version of a crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I use the nightly version of a crate (from [crates.io](https://crates.io/))? Sorry, I should know, but I cannot find this anywhere in the documentation. I assume that I put something in `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nightly" in Rust refers to the development version of the compiler and language. There is no such a thing as a "nightly version" of a crate.

However, you can use the development version of a crate by using the code repository as a source, for example, in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
foobar = { git = "https://github.com/user/foobar", branch = "dev_branch" }
```

See also [the full syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/126#issuecomment-48101852) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704573/is-it-possible-to-have-cargo-fetch-dependencies-from-a-private-remote-git) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070903/how-to-tell-cargo-to-use-a-git-repository-as-source-for-an-indirect-dependency-i) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786956/can-i-add-a-dependent-crate-that-is-a-subdirectory-in-a-git-repository).